# Does the order of parameters in classList methods matter?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-manipulation

I have four css classes that seperated based on their functionality, `.openModalStyle` and `.closeModalStyle` contain appearing/disappearing styles,  `.openModalTransition` and `.closeModalTransition` contain transition property for that styles.

I want to know if the order of tokens matter for classList methods or not, because transition  should be attached before styles.

```js
let modal = document.querySelector("modal");

// style before transition
modal.classList.add("openModalStyle");
modal.classList.add("openModalTransition");


// transition before style
modal.classList.add("openModalTransition");
modal.classList.add("openModalStyle");

// want to make sure both work properly in all browsers
```

```css
    .modal{
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: #f00;
    }
    
    
    /* change opacity */
    .openModalStyle{
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .closeModalStyle{
      opacity: 0;
    }


    /* apply transitions */
    /* they are repeated styles, but i need to keep them seperated for some reason */

    .openModalTransition{
      transition: opacity 2s;
    }
    .closeModalTransition{
      transition: opacity 2s;
    }
```

```html
<div class="modal"></div>
```

Comment: Your stylesheet is the one that controls wether what style should be applied based on order and specificty. The order of a class in a `class` attribute or set by `classList` has no influence.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking if it matters whether you do `x.classList.add("openModalStyle");x.classList.add("openModalTransition")` or `x.classList.add("openModalTransition");x.classList.add("openModalStyle")`

Comment: The order in a classList does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter in the `classList` as you just adding a class to the element,

Also, the order at `CSS` in most cases doesn't matter, only in some cases it matters, It comes up any time multiple CSS selectors match an element with the exact same [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).